# The Jacobian of the exponential along a geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, geodesic

I am reading a paper that uses but does not define the following concept: what is understood by "the Jacobian of the exponential map along a geodesic (beetween two points)"? Is this only defined for geodesics, or for general curves as well? Must the geodesics be length-minimizing?

Comment: The 'Jacobian' usually refers to the first derivative, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant. Or does it say Jacobi fields?

Comment: Can you also provide the link to your paper?